# What does the phrase "block is sliding upwards" mean here?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

So there was this question I came across.

Now, there is the last line of the question that bothers me.

> As a result, **the cube slides upwards** and the block is moving with an acceleration a.

[image]

What does that phrase mean ? does it mean that the cube is accelerating or not ? Because if its accelerating upwards then there is no way to find the value of that acceleration.

For m, we can write using Newton's Second law in the vertical direction :
(Assuming upwards motion to be positive)
$$ F - (mg + \mu N_{1}) = ma_1$$ where $N_1$ is the normal reaction due to its contact with the bigger block.

Similarly for $M$, we can write :
(Assuming leftwards motion to be positive)
$$2\mu mg - N_1 = 2mg$$

Using the second equation we can find the value of the normal reaction but we can't find the value of $a_1$. Also is F also acting on the bigger block.

Comment: You can find the value of $N_1$. The acceleration of the block is the clue.

Comment: @Mechanic yeah I can already do that. How can I find the value of $a_1$ ?

Answer (score 1):

As per the above question, it is not necessary to find the absolute value of acceleration of the block, rather they have asked to find the Force from all the given data

Use the first formula that you have mentioned and instead of Normal substitute the pseudo force acting on the small block. At the end you will get the value of F in terms of m and a